# Accessing Google Apis from Android Emulator using Apache Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, google-api

I have an apache cordova app that makes use of the google apis, i.e., `www.googleapis.com`. In my `index.html` I have set my CSP as follows

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.googleapis.com data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com ">
```

and my `config.xml` looks as follows

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myapp.www" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Building and running this app in the browser works as expected, i.e., I can access and use the google apis. However, building and running the app in the android emulator (intel x86) gives me the following error

```
Refused to coonect to 'https://www.googleapis.com/.... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.googleapis.com data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com ". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Is this something to do with the emulator? Can the emulator call google apis? Or, am I neglecting to do something in my `config.xml`?

Comment: I hate the exact same issue

Comment: Did you solve the problem yet?